# What to do if I cannot connect to WiFi that requires authentication without restarting?

Tags: mac, wifi

My Mac has often a problem on connecting to the WiFi at a cafe that requires authentication (either SMS or email, or just click on "accept"). It does not have such a problem when connecting to any normal WiFi that requires password.

Such WiFi that needs authentication is usually at chained types cafes, including Starbucks and McDonalds.

In these cases, when I cannot connect, usually restarting resolves the problem. But I'm very reluctant to bother to restarting just to connect to WiFi, as it happens so frequently (literally every day, though it cannot necessarily connect every day).

My iPhone has no problem on connecting, and my Mac also has no problem when connecting to password-based WiFi.

Except restarting, how can I connect to it? I already tried the following command, but it does not fix the problem.

```
networksetup -setairportpower en0 off
networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

---

Here is an example of the result of `ifconfig en0`. Again, WiFi did not work at all but once I restart my Mac, it suddenly started to work...

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 8c:85:90:00:05:e0
    inet6 fe80::51:172e:3497:5387%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x5
    inet 192.168.23.117 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.23.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

---

Here is the resulf of `netstat -rn | grep default`:

```
default            172.17.0.2         UGSc            0        0     en0
default                                 fe80::%utun0                    UGcI          utun0
default                                 fe80::%utun2                    UGcI          utun2
```

Comment: Sometimes, just opening a web browser first can make the difference, I've found, [but that's entirely anecdotal, I have no real evidence to support that it would work.]

Comment: @Tetsujin I usually keep opening a web browser, so when I open my Mac and connect to the WiFi, the browser is always open. I quit my browser and launch it again, but it almost always does not resolve (still, in some very rare cases, it works)...

Comment: I'm a bit unclear here...is it *not* connecting to the WiFi at all until you restart or does it connect, but you just can't browse?

Comment: @Allan If "connect" means the icon on the menubar turns to black, yes it is connected. But then when I tried to open a new tab or switch a page in an existing tab, it does not load nor go into the authentication page, just showing "cannot connect to..." error.

Comment: You've tried navigating to a new page (i.e. Google.com or Apple.com)?  I found that works many times to bring up the authentication page.  Can you post the output of  `ifconfig en0` when you are connected?

Comment: @Allan Yes I tried to navigate and I also know it works (actually when I connect, I always open a new tab and add a random address). I already went back home, so now it is not possible to get the result of `ifconfig en0`.

Comment: The good news, it looks like, is that you're connected.  Try pinging the gateway (use `netstat -rn | grep default` to get it).  Then try pinging an outside address (23.193.219.136 for Apple.com).  Let's see if we can narrow this to a DNS or an authentication issue.....

Comment: @Allan Sorry I already restarted it, but regarding the second point (ping), it did not work (and what I tried was coincidentally Apple's!)

Comment: Were you able to ping the gateway?

Comment: @Allan I updated. And the resulf of `ping 23.193.219.136` is `ping: sendto: No buffer space available
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7`